# Docker Compose copies one folder but not another

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose

I am still learning Docker and this situation has me stumped. Docker will copy one folder to the image/container but the other folder it skips and I can't figure out why.

Docker desktop 4.X Ubuntu (Linux) container
.NET 5.0 Blazor application

So in the application build the following two folders are output:

[image]

In the container though only one folder is there

[image]

My first thought would be caching but I am using `docker-compose build --no-cache` and `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`.

I don't think the Dockerfile is the problem, or else I would not see any folders.

### Update

Added Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 465

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["./Email.Shared/Email.Shared.csproj", "./Email.Shared/"]
COPY ["./Email.API/Email.API.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Email.API.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Email.API"
RUN dotnet build "Email.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Email.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Email.API.dll", "--urls", "http://+:5150"]
```

Comment: Well, I would like to see Dockerfile, since all the magic happens there... Assuming nothing specials is happening in Compose file, besides the definition of services.

Comment: The thing that strikes me is that you mention this being a .NET Core 3.1 container but the path in your screenshot is referencing `net5.0` (i.e. .NET 5.0).

Comment: @MattThalman...I'm such an idiot. Yes it is .NET 5.0. I've updated the OP

Comment: @StefanGolubović Added dockerfile