# Copying Docker volumes to server

Tags: docker

I am still new to Docker but progressing through the Pluralsight learning path and lots of articles. I have learned to use volumes to persist data when containers stop and restart.

My question is how should I deploy volumes or is this bad design to have a volume dependency?

I do my local development and run things locally and all is great. I push to Docker Hub and pull down to my staging server. All working quite nicely EXCEPT emails.

The emails fail because the email templates are  stored in a volume.

I am using Ubuntu with Solar-Putty so I can easily ftp the files into the proper volume location on the staging server.

or

I could ftp my entire volume to the Ubuntu staging server but in so doing do I corrupt some sort of Docker meta data unique id?

What is the best way to approach this dev ops process?

Comment: Asking for best approach is general not such a good idea, since it tends to be opinion based. Use a bind mount and supply the templates from the host. Or generate the templates inside the container when you build it. It all really depends on how you are generating or making these template. Do you need to modify them continuously? Is there any value in re-using parts of them between different hosts ect.

Comment: So this is an educational project and no production implications. I've read such differing takes on bind mounts. On of the pluralsight instructor says they are more secure but docker documentations says Volumes is preferred.

As far as generating the templates at build time...that's was failing and what lead me down this path. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441227/docker-compose-copies-one-folder-but-not-other)

Comment: Why are the email templates in a volume?  (Do you have a specific workflow where another team updates them; the application has editable templates as a user-visible option; something else?)  When you go to deploy the application, is there a specific version of the templates that needs to be deployed with it?

Comment: *On of the pluralsight instructor says they are more secure but docker documentations says Volumes is preferred.* That's just nonsense. They are 2 different things meant for different use cases. Also, a bind mount **IS** a volume. It's just a bind-mounted volume.